# Entity Framework group by left join query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, group-by, sum, left-join

The Result should look like this
[image: result should look like this]

I've started to use Entity Framework for one month so I am not familiar with linq queries. The query I wrote in SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    om0001.CUSTOMER, om0001.ITEM_CODE, 
    SUM(om0001.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, 
    SUM(ep0001.EXPORT_AMOUNT) AS EXPORT_AMOUNT
FROM
    om0001
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ep0001 ON om0001.ID = ep0001.om0001_ID
GROUP BY 
    om0001.CUSTOMER, om0001.ITEM_CODE;
```

When I run this query in SQL, it runs well so I tried to convert it to linq queries.

What I made so far is

```
var testjoin = from om0001 in EF.om0001
               join ep0001 in EF.ep0001 on om0001.ID equals ep0001.om0001_ID
               into jointable
               from z in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
               group z by new {om0001.CUSTOMER, om0001.ITEM_CODE } into g
               select new
                      {
                          CUSTOMER = g.Key.CUSTOMER,
                          ITEM_CODE = g.Key.ITEM_CODE,
                          om0001SUMamount = g.Sum(x => x.AMOUNT),
                          ep0001EXPORTsumAmount = g.Sum(y => y.EXPORT_AMOUNT)
                      };
```

The problem over this linq query is I can not get om0001SUMamount. I get only ep0001 column data. Please help

Comment: Please add your sample data and add the result you expect

Comment: It would make it easier for us to tailor the answer if you'd give us your classes

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, I cant peek into your EF database, so I created some sample data (the 'item' class structures are implied):

```
var EF = new efClass {
    om0001 = new List<om0001item> {
        new om0001item { ID = 0, CUSTOMER = 0, ITEM_CODE = 0, AMOUNT = 10 },
        new om0001item { ID = 1, CUSTOMER = 0, ITEM_CODE = 0, AMOUNT = 20 },
        new om0001item { ID = 2, CUSTOMER = 1, ITEM_CODE = 1, AMOUNT = 30 },
        new om0001item { ID = 3, CUSTOMER = 1, ITEM_CODE = 1, AMOUNT = 40 }
    },
    ep0001 = new List<ep0001item> {
        new ep0001item { om0001_ID = 0, EXPORT_AMOUNT = -20 },
        new ep0001item { om0001_ID = 1, EXPORT_AMOUNT = -20 }        
    }
};
```

With this data, I created a query that frankly feels inelegant and left me disappointed, but that's the nature of left joins in LINQ:

```
var testjoin = from om0001 in EF.om0001
    join ep0001 in EF.ep0001 on om0001.ID equals ep0001.om0001_ID into jointable
    select new { om0001, ep0001 = jointable.DefaultIfEmpty() } into combined
    group combined by new { 
        combined.om0001.CUSTOMER,
        combined.om0001.ITEM_CODE
    } into g
    select new {
       CUSTOMER = g.Key.CUSTOMER,
       ITEM_CODE = g.Key.ITEM_CODE,
       om0001SUMamount = g.Sum(x => x.om0001.AMOUNT),
       ep0001EXPORTsumAmount = g.Sum(x => x?.ep0001.Sum(y => y?.EXPORT_AMOUNT ?? 0)) 
    };
```

Bottom line is that when you group by 'jointable', you've lost ep0001 references.  So select both ep0001 and om0001 into a new 'combined' object, and then group based off of it.

When I created a javascript library ([fluent-data](https://github.com/paulwilcox/fluent-data)) that had some LINQ-like functionality, I developed a lot of respect and compassion for the LINQ developers.  Nevertheless, I don't know why they don't just create a left join operator to add so much more value to all the C# developers who use LINQ.

Comment: the code you gave me is good. But `y => y?.EXPORT_AMOUNT ?? 0)` this part says lamdba exception null value error appeared so I changed that part to  `g.Sum(y => y.ep0001.Sum(x=> x.EXPORT_AMOUNT))` It does not show error but when I run the program it say null value exception. What is the problem over here?

Comment: I edited the code subtly.  For the line in question, try `g.Sum(x => x?.ep0001?.Sum(y => y?.EXPORT_AMOUNT ?? 0)) `.

Comment: still same error. The error says "an expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator"

Comment: It's because when Entity Framework works with SQL it has to make translations that it doesn't otherwise have to make when working with C# objects.  Try `g.Sum(x => x == null ? null : x.ep0001.Sum(y => y == null ? null : y.EXPORT_AMOUNT ?? 0))`  If that doesn't work, hopefully someone else can help you, or if not, I'll take a look tomorrow but my ability may be limited for this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for your support. It helps me a lot. I tried the code but now it gives another error which is "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and null.

Comment: `g.Sum(x => x == null ? (int?)null : x.ep0001.Sum(y => y == null ? (int?)null : y.EXPORT_AMOUNT))`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a table with `Oms` (actually Om00001, but I'm not going to write all those 0001 over and over again), and a table with `Eps`, and you have a one-to-many relation between `Oms` and `Eps`: Every `Om` has zero or more `Eps`, and every `Ep` belongs to exactly one `Om`, namely the `Om` that foreign key `EpId` refers to.

If you have followed [Entity Framework code first conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) you will have classes similar to the following:

```
class Om
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Customer {get; set;}
    public string ItemCode {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Om has zero or more Eps (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Ep> Eps {get; set;}
}

class Ep
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Amount {get; set;}
    public int ExportAmount {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Ep belongs to exactly one Om, using foreign key
    public int OmId {get; set;}
    public virtual Om Om {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough for entity framework to detect your one-to-many relationship. Because I followed the conventions, there is no need for Attributes, nor fluent API. If you want different table names, or columns, you need fluent API / attributes.

> In entity framework the non-virtual properties represent the columns of your tables, the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

### Solution using GroupJoin

```
var result = dbContext.Oms.GroupJoin(dbContext.Eps,
    om => om.Id,                   // from every Om take the primary key
    ep => ep.OmId,                 // from every ep take the foreign key to the Om

    (om, epsOfThisOm) => new       // from every om and all eps having the correct foreign key
    {                              // make one new object
        // Select only the properties that you plan to use:
        Customer = om.Customer,
        ItemCode = om.ItemCode,

        Amount = epsOfThisOm.Sum(ep => ep.Amount);
        ExportAmount = epsOfThisOm.Sum(ep => ep.ExportAmount);
    });
```

### Solution using the virtual ICollection

Instead of executing a GroupJoin, you could also use the virtual ICollection.

**Requirement**: from every Om, give me the Customer and the ItemCode, and the sum of all Amounts of its Eps, and the sum of all ExportAmounts of its Eps.

```
var result = dbContext.Oms.Select(om => new
{
    Customer = om.Customer,
    ItemCode = om.ItemCode,

    Amount = om.Eps.Sum(ep => ep.Amount);
    ExportAmount = om.Eps.Sum(ep => ep.ExportAmount);
});
```

This looks much neater, and it matches more directly your requirement. Entity framework knows the relations, and will do the correct GroupJoin for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying your code but met a problem.

```var result = EF.om0001.GroupJoin(EF.ep0001, om0001 => om0001.ID, ep0001 => ep0001.om0001_ID, (om0001, epsOfThisOm) => new
            {
                Customer = om0001.CUSTOMER,
                ItemCode = om0001.ITEM_CODE,
                Amount = epsOfThisOm.Sum(ep => om0001.AMOUNT),
                ExportAmount = epsOfThisOm.Sum(ep => ep.EXPORT_AMOUNT)

            });```

This is What I tried because I could not find ep.Amount. ep does not have Amount does not know reason. 

```Amount = om.Eps.Sum(ep => ep.Amount);```

Comment: You didn't write your ep0001 class. Apparently it does not have a property `Amount`. Better edit your question, add relevant parts of your om00001 and ep00001 at the end, and write this code what you tried. An endless list or remarks won't help future readers.